# Hash the result from the database , Is it possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't know if the question wording is correct or not, but I want to do the following:

I have a table named **sales** It contain following columns:

```
    ------------------------------------------------
    | PRODUCT_NAME | PRODUCT_QUANTITY | ExpierDate |
    ------------------------------------------------
```

if I `SELECT * FROM sales` then the result will be :

```
------------------------------------------------
| PRODUCT_NAME | PRODUCT_QUANTITY | ExpierDate |
------------------------------------------------
| TestName     |        5         | 2021-6-12  |
| TestName     |        2         | 2024-10-18 |
------------------------------------------------
```

What I need to do is to select query and get the result look like this :

```
    ------------------------------------------------
    | PRODUCT_NAME | PRODUCT_QUANTITY | ExpierDate |
    ------------------------------------------------
    | TestName     |        1        | 2021-6-12   |
    | TestName     |        2        | 2021-6-12   |
    | TestName     |        3        | 2021-6-12   |
    | TestName     |        4        | 2021-6-12   |
    | TestName     |        5        | 2021-6-12   |
    | TestName     |        1        | 2024-10-18  |
    | TestName     |        2        | 2024-10-18  |
    ------------------------------------------------
```

Is this even possible ?

How can I do this..!?

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: The date in your second last row looks incorrect?

Comment: P.Salmon sorry of this ... now it is ok

Comment: jarlh Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.0.1 On XAMPP

Comment: @AdeebMark Correct me if I am wrong - you want per product and per date (groups) a list in ascending order of quantity from 1 to the actual value? In essence generating / selecting from numbers table which then groups by product and date and selected value?

Comment: Lets say ... yes !

Comment: you can create pseudo quantity table and join this table to fill up the data you want.

Comment: there is another easy fix ? T. Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend directly using a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select product_name, product_quantity, expire_date, 1 as n
      from sales s
      union all
      select product_name, product_quantity, expire_date, n + 1
      from cte
      where n < product_quantity
     )
select *
from cte
order by product_name, product_quantity, expire_date, n;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fce3e29d53df591c42786444cd151189) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

As I mention in comment, with `cte` create pseudo data to fill up the row is really easy:

```
with RECURSIVE quan(quantity) AS (
 SELECT 1 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT quantity+1 FROM quan WHERE quantity < 10 --you may have to increase this
)
SELECT tb.PRODUCT_NAME ,quan.quantity as PRODUCT_QUANTITY,tb.ExpierDate 
  FROM [tb]  -- your result table
  JOIN quan on tb.PRODUCT_QUANTITY >= quan.quantity
 ORDER BY tb.time,quan.quantity
```

here is [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=354df39a6a4275dd3ad60e97cc233c3c) with pseudo data.
using `int` column as `time` column in pseudo data but I think query itself will still work.
In recursive cte you may have to increase the where part to create more pseudo quantity data depend on your max quantity.

Comment: Unrecognized statement near with ?!